# What is this abandoned plane?

Tags: aviation-history, aircraft-identification

Does anyone knows what type of plane is this and its model?

[image]
(Source: YouTube channel AssombradO.com.br)

Comment: What is the source of this picture?

Comment: Ron Beyer I took it from a YouTube channel intro, but they never metioned nothing about it...

Comment: Looks like a Douglas DC-3 to me, but you might find it under C-47, or Dakota depending on its use and operator.

Comment: Looks too long forward of the wings for a DC-3.

Comment: @RonBeyer From the posted answer it's a Super DC-3, stretched 39" ahead of the wing, and 40" aft.

Comment: @Airsick - that and the missing engine exaggerates the length.

Comment: *Which* YouTube channel? Unless you personally took the picture, you've acquired a suitable license, or you know for a fact that it is in the public domain, then if you want to reproduce it as you're doing here the very least you can do is link to the place where you got it.

Comment: E.P. as the picture was used by the channel without any credits or info, I thought it was public domain and that I could do the same :) And answering your question, it was AssombradO.com.br channel.

Comment: And as I said, it was on YouTube in public view, so there's no harm in posting it as far as they do the same every video but in a bigger scale for everyone to see...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[image]
Source: [dailymail.co.uk](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2643794/Left-rot-The-eerie-wreckage-crashed-U-S-Navy-aircraft-abandoned-Icelandic-beach-40-years-ago.html)

It's a crashed [Super DC-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_C-47_Skytrain#Super_DC-3_(R4D-8)) (C-117D) in Iceland.

> - On Nov 24 1973, the US Navy airplane - a Douglas Super DC-3 - was forced to crash land on Sólheimasandur beach
> - The crew all survived the impact, but the plane was abandoned rather than recovered - and lies there still
> - All that's left is the plane's fuselage amid rumours a local farmer stole the tail to mysteriously sell it on

It started its life as a [C-47A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_C-47_Skytrain) with construction number (CN) 12554, the 2,554<sup>th</sup> in sequence. It was for the USAF (tail-number 42-92722). It was then converted to become an R4D-5 (Super DC-3 / C-117D) for the US Navy, and was given the new CN 43309 (tail-number 17171).*

[image]

First flight was 1944. It crash landed after encountering icing conditions en route on a supply mission to a radar station ([aviation-safety.net](https://aviation-safety.net/database/record.php?id=19731121-0)).

---

* [rzjets.net](http://rzjets.net/aircraft/?reg=213516) and [abcdlist.nl](http://www.abcdlist.nl/douglas_longbeach_02.html)

Comment: Good grief, it looks like the prop doesn't even clear the fuselage!

Comment: @chrylis: Or the ground, it seems...

Comment: 92722 (MSN 12554) to USAAF Feb 17, 1944, to US Marine Corps as R4D-5 BuNo 17171 Feb 17, 1944

17171 (MSN 12554) ex USAAF 42-92722, to US Navy 17Feb44.  VMR 253 Aug44.  HDN MAW-4 Nov44.  HDN MAG 15 10Nov45.  
     Mar Fair WC Nov45.  San Diego Dec45.  Stored Jun46.  Quonset Pt Feb48.  VR-l Jun48. 
     Converted to R4D-8 MSN 43309  Nov51.  MAG-11 Apr62.  Redesignated C-117D 18Sep62.   http://www.joebaugher.com/navy_serials/thirdseries2.html

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- - the DC-3/C-47 had about 5" of clearance between prop tip and fuselage. See http://www.enginehistory.org/Operations/DC-3CrewChiefNotes.pdf and search for "clearance". I imagine that the C-117's were similar. Why would you need more? :-)