# What is this radial-engined US Navy aircraft in Iceland?

Tags: aircraft-identification, us-navy

My parents are traveling in Iceland and sent me a few pictures of an old radial-engined aircraft. It has "United States Navy" markings on the side, "Keflavik 17131" on the tail, and "191" on the nose. There's a picture of one wing with two engines, so I assume it's got four total. Unfortunately I don't have an exact location, except that it's in Iceland.

I'd love to know what this is, but perhaps also how it might have ended up abandoned by the Navy in Iceland.

[image: Fuselage, full length, with United States Navy down the side]

[image: Closeup on the tail, with faded lettering saying "Keflavik 17131"]

[image: One wing with two radial engines. Each engine pod also has landing gear underneath]

[image: Rear view of the wing with the two engines]

[image: Aircraft nose, bearing the numbers 191]

Comment: Another in Iceland: [What is this abandoned plane?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/48491/14897)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As others have mentioned, it's a [C-117D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_C-47_Skytrain#Super_DC-3_(R4D-8)). Regarding that particular airframe's history/status:

It was on display 1977–2002 at the then US Naval Air Station Keflavik:

> With the end of the war in Europe, Keflavik Airport became a transit point for aircraft returning from the European Theater of Operations to the United States.
>
> — Wikipedia: [Naval Air Station Keflavik](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Naval_Air_Station_Keflavik&oldid=1023049689)

The below US Navy photo from 2002 shows the process of moving it to the Icelandic Aviation Museum. It was to be restored, but evidently that has not happened.

> [image]
> — [wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:US_Navy_020916-N-9958S-003_Navy_C-117_Gooneybird_is_dismantled_for_future_museum_display.jpg)

The caption reads:

> Naval Air Station Keflavik, Iceland (Sep. 16, 2002) -- Members of the stations Fire and Emergency Services (FES) finish dismantling a C-117D "Super Gooneybird". Bureau #17191. The aircraft had been on static display aboard the station since 1977, and is to be donated to the Icelandic Aviation Museum, where it will be fully restored. U.S. Navy photo by Journalist 2nd Class Stephen Sheedy. (RELEASED) Note: As of 2013, aircraft remains dismantled and exposed to the elements at the museum.

Since [at least 2019](https://www.flickr.com/photos/erwinalexander/48014947911) it's been at that location you have, the [Hnjótur Museum](https://www.google.com/search?&q=Hnj%C3%B3tur%20Museum):

> [image]
> — Google Earth (Google Maps [link](https://www.google.com/maps/search/N65.56238+W24.158234))

Comment: "It was to be restored, but evidently that has not happened"  today's understatement!  Heh!

Comment: I paid a visit to the Hnjótur Museum in 2015 at which point that aircraft was already located there. I don't remember all the details but I think the plane was handed over to Egill Olafsson, the founder of the museum, back in the day. He died long before 2015 so the plane has been rotting there for much longer I suppose.

Answer (score 9):

It appears to be a [Douglas C-117](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_C-47_Skytrain#Super_DC-3_(R4D-8)) which is a C-47 with more powerful engines. Tail number 17191 flew out of Iceland

https://www.airliners.net/photo/USA-Navy/Douglas-C-117D-DC-3S/2157319

From the linked website:

> Standing in front of the weather office, 17191 is ready for another flight to one of the radar stations around Iceland.

The aircraft has the same KEFLAVIK and tail number markings

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Based on the third and fourth pictures I thought it had four engines, but now I see that the fuselage attached between the two engines. Any idea what the aircraft is doing there in Iceland?

Comment: @AshleyStrout It was probably based there. The US had a military base in Iceland until 2006 ([NAS Keflavik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naval_Air_Station_Keflavik)).

Comment: Sad to see a once beautiful plane like this, abandoned and crumbling to a pile of garbage. Also makes me feel old--it looks like it's been abandoned almost forever, but I can remember 1976 (when the picture was taken) quite clearly...

Comment: @Jerry Coffin when I hear stories of crazy rich people buying half million dollar yachts I think "why wouldn't you buy one of these planes and restore it instead!?" It would be a cool plans to arrive anywhere, especially in the classic livery.

Answer (score 2):

That’s a Douglas R4D, the Navy version of the C-47/DC-3.

Comment: Can you add some sources to your answer please?  As it currently is, your answer is at risk of being deleted.

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t. I just know what the DC-3 looks like, and being a Navy aircraft, I can extrapolate that it is, indeed, an R4D.

Comment: It was built as a C-47A-20-DK Skytrain 42-93105 (MSN 12980) for the USAAF Apr 12, 1944, then transferred to US Navy as R4D-5 BuNo 17191 Apr 12, 1944, and then later redesignated as C-117D. https://flydc3.de/planes/detail/265/

Comment: 17191 (MSN 12980) ex USAAF 42-93105. To US Navy 12Apr44. NATS 12Apr44. VR-3 Aug44. VR-9 22Dec44. VR-1 Feb45. VR-7 Apr45. VR-3 Aug45. Jacksonville May46. NART Glenview May46. Converted to R4D-8 with new MSN 43379, returned to USN from Douglas December 1952. Europe Jun59 to 18Sep62. To C-117D 18Sep62. Europe 18Sep62 to Dec70. Mildenhall 1971 to Oct73. WFU. Retired from service 1973; in 1987 was on display at NAF Keflavik, Iceland. Moved Sept 2002 to Egils Olafssonair Minja-Og Fugminjasafn at Bjargtangar, Iceland. http://www.joebaugher.com/navy_serials/thirdseries2.html

Answer (score 1):

It's an [R4D](https://www.history.navy.mil/content/history/museums/nnam/explore/collections/aircraft/c/c-117d-skytrain0.html), a Naval version of the Douglas C-47/DC-3.

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour, le C-117 est la dernière version (R4D8) du mythique DC3. Outre les moteurs plus puissants (1450 ou 1475 ch au lieu de 1200), il est "nouveau" à hauteur de 75% des pièces, même si la ressembalnce avec le C47 reste frappante. Fuselage plus long, queue "genre DC4", nouveaux panneaux extérieurs d'ailes,, train totalement caréné sont les principales différences. Gros échec commercial, les 101 avions construits (la plupart par transformation de DC3) sont des raretés pour lesquelles un musée donnerait une fortune. Voir ce C-117 pourrir est une honte.

---

Translation using Google Translate -

> Hello, the C-117 is the latest version (R4D8) of the legendary DC3. In addition to the more powerful engines (1450 or 1475 hp instead of 1200), it is "new" up to 75% of the parts, even if the resemblance with the C47 remains striking. Longer fuselage, "DC4-like" tail, new outer wing panels, fully faired undercarriage are the main differences. A big commercial failure, the 101 planes built (most by DC3 transformation) are rarities for which a museum would give a fortune. Seeing that C-117 rot is a shame.

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.se Sorry, but this is an English community. Could you translate your post? Otherwise it will have to be removed. Thank you.

Comment: @Federico I actually happen to know French - am I allowed to submit an edit request with a translation?

Comment: @AshleyStrout theoretically you could. the problem is that it would be hard to verify that the translation is accurate. and the user probably won't learn about the requirement to post in English.

Comment: @AshleyStrout please verify the accuracy of the translation that has been provided.

Comment: @ThomasPerry looks good to me!